# how to quantify/analyze correlation of two biomarkers over time?

Tags: correlation, panel-data

As a biologist, I'm interested in analyzing the dynamics of two biomarkers (A and B) over time of multiple subjects and how each biomarker is correlated with a disease phenotype/response to drug treatment (and if combination will be better to be correlated with a phenotype).

I've plotted the level of each biomarker together in one plot (2 lines over several time points) and visually there seem to be certain correlation between the two biomarkers (they both go up and down at the same time).

I'm wondering what statistical test or framework is designed to evaluate/quantify the longitudinal relationship of two biomarkers over time?

Thanks!